# Replication In Apache Ignite

Tags: java, ignite, in-memory-database, gridgain

I am running Apache Ignite in "REPLICATED MODE" with two server nodes up and running. 
The Cache is in "PRIMARY_SYNC" write mode, with "ATOMIC" atomicity and number of backups being "0".

From the Client, I am making requests via TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder and I configured those two server addresses in the IP finder list.

I got a question that in practice, while replication is happening between two nodes say from X -> Y, some data is being copied, and Y doesn't have the latest records. 
Let's say a request lands on "Y" from the client. Will that be actually served from "Y"? Because "Y" has stale data. I want to understand how this works.
 And I worry because I gave write mode as only "primary sync" and there could be asynchronous data updates between X-Y.

Answer (score 1):

By default, for key-value API, `readFromBackups` setting is `false` and you will read the latest value. SQL will read whatever is present on node.

Comment: So when creating SQL tables, we need to make sure of FULL_SYNC to happen between nodes?

Comment: What about SqlFieldsQuery API?

Comment: I guess so! SqlFieldsQuery is SQL.

Comment: Just to confirm I gave ZERO backups for both k-v cache and SQL tables. And K-V cache write mode PRIMARY_SYNC and SQL tables write mode FULL_SYNC. If I do that I am guessing in both server nodes data should be replicated and queries will execute on updated data. Am I right?

Comment: I guess so. I don't understand why you state you have zero backups when your caches are in fact replicated. Backups are meaningless with replicated caches.

Comment: Ya I understand backups are meaningless.. I stated that because for CREATE TABLE thing I need to explicitly mention "BACKUPS=0" right? That's why

Comment: No, you don't need to do that.

Comment: I am doing that because I saw in visor terminal that for one cache a key is stored in "backup" node as 12/3 where 12 keys in primary and 3 keys in backup. But in my code i never mentioned anywhere saying setBackups. So I am assuming it's creating backups..

Comment: Replicated cache has backups on every node. I'm not sure what 12/3 means.

Comment: Sorry.. my theory was wrong.. now i understood. what i need to do is just put FULL_SYNC as i was not using transactions.. I faced an issue of consistency guarantee. I thought in Replication mode PRIMARY_SYNC will guarantee consistency but it didn't as I thought no backups will be there and all keys will be stored in all primary nodes.. but I was wrong. I understood that in replication a key will defintely store in primary node and as a backup key in all other nodes. Thank you.